# Http POST in BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Greetings,

I am trying to setup a server connection from my BlackBerry Application . I was able to get a response code on the status of the server. Now i have a few values which i have to POST to the server

Its like a registration page values(username, password, age ) have to be sent to the server .

```
        ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
        ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
        connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);
        if (connDesc != null)
        {
            HttpConnection httpConn;
            httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
            try
            {
                final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Dialog.alert("Response code: " + Integer.toString(iResponseCode));
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Thats the code i used to get the response code.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me how i can make a POST request to the server..
the server url for status was company.com/app/version/stats

when it for register it would be 
company.com/app/register

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ...
httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();    
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("username",name);
httpConn.setRequestProperty("password",pass);
....
```

Comment: i got the response code as success but the values didnt get added to the server ..

Comment: Use wireShark for check your sended request. If it is correct, than error is in the server side (maybe you need to add User-Agent or sth else..)

Answer (score 6):

What type of a POST do you use? If you are just passing key-value pairs, then it should be a POST of a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type.

So, what lacks youe code is:

1). Set a proper content-type on your connection:

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

2). Prepare the content to be sent to the server via the POST:

```
URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
encPostData.append("username", username);
encPostData.append("password", password);
encPostData.append("age", age);
byte[] postData = encPostData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

3). Set content-length for the connection (this step may be optional - try without this first, probably the BB OS is smart enough to set this automatically):

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length));
```

4). Open an OutputStream and write the content to it (the code is simplified):

```
OutputStream os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
os.write(postData);
os.flush();
```

Comment: Hi, It is giving null pointer exception. Something related to OutputStream and postData, but postData has some value I don't know then why it is giving null pointer exception.

Comment: @AhmadShahwaiz: Please ask a separate SO question, posting your code and stack trace.

Comment: @Archimed I have please this if you can answer this, Thanks. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377021/blackberry-httppost-null-pointer-exception-java