# make HTTP Post request from blackberry java application

Tags: blackberry, http-post

In my Blackberry java native application, i am making a call to a dotnet web service whose Request and Response format is defined as below. Here In response XML is being returned. I have been searching the forums and trying for 2-3 days but no success...

Request format :

> POST /cinews.asmx/GetSeatLayout HTTP/1.1 
>   Host: webservices.mclients.com  
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
>   Content-Length: length
>
> strCinews=string&strTransId1=string&lngSessionId=string&blnScreenOnTop=string&strMergeOption=string&strAreaCats=string

Response format :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
```

xml

Comment: And your question is?  You seem to be getting the response, so I am guessing your question is not how to send an http POST request or receive a response, which I think leaves asking how to process the XML, but I'm not sure.  Please clarify.  However regardless of your actual question, it would surprise me if there was not already a similar question answered here, so I recommend you clarify your question and search.

Comment: Thanks for replying peter. My question actually is how to send the request? I haven't made this type of request earlier so please point me to some reference(similar to my case). The Request and Response format (for the dotnet web service i want to call) described above is given by the person who created the web service. So my question now is how to make a HTTP Post request  to that dotnet web service? I have all the input parameters available like strCinews, strTransId1, lngSessionId etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Http POST in BlackBerry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184223/http-post-in-blackberry)

Comment: @Nate Thanks for the reply. I have just gone through the post adviced by you. I am making connection with "http://webservices.mclients.com/cinews.asmx", i am getting response as 200..it is ok i think.. but where should i tell about the web service method name i.e. GetSeatLayout.

Comment: `/cinews.asmx/GetSeatLayout` is the end of your URL.  If you look at the **question** I linked to, that would be in the variable named `url` that's shown in the question.  For the rest of the solution, see the **answers**.

Comment: @Nate : It is giving 500 as Response code...

Comment: 500 is a server error.  You'll have to debug it on the server side, or search for information on the internet about that error code with that particular web service.